# synchronization in simple socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, pthreads

I want to create a simple multithreaded chat application in C using api. For the beginning, i wrote a simple  server communicating with client but there is a problem in the order messages sent.

example output:

in server

*new_sock socket number: 4

Server:hello client

Client:hello server

Server:how are you?

Client:

Server:

in client

Server:hello client

Client:hello server

Server:how are you?

Client:

```
    //server code
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

void* connection_handler(void* socket_descriptor)
{

    int socket = *(int *)socket_descriptor;

    int n;

    char server_buffer[256];
    memset(server_buffer, 0, sizeof(server_buffer));

    printf("Server:");
    gets(server_buffer);

    send(socket, server_buffer, strlen(server_buffer), 0);
    memset(server_buffer, 0, sizeof(server_buffer));

    while ((n = recv(socket, server_buffer, 255, 0)) > 0)
    {
        server_buffer[n] = '\0';
        printf("Client:%s\n", server_buffer);
        memset(server_buffer, 0, sizeof(server_buffer));
        printf("Server:");
        gets(server_buffer);
        send(socket, server_buffer, strlen(server_buffer), 0);
        memset(server_buffer, 0, sizeof(server_buffer));

        n = 0;
    }

    close(socket);

    free(socket_descriptor);

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int server_sock, client_sock, portno, client_len, n;
    int *new_sock;

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("ERROR: no port provided.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(server_sock < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: opening socket.");
        exit(1);
    }

    portno = atoi(argv[1]);


    memset((char *)&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));


    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if( bind(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0 )
    {
        printf("ERROR: binding socket.");
        exit(1);
    }


    listen(server_sock, 5);

    pthread_t handler_thread;


    while( client_sock = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_len) )
    {


        new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        printf("*new_sock socket number: %d\n", *new_sock);

        if( pthread_create(&handler_thread, (void *)NULL, connection_handler, (void *)new_sock) < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: creating thread\n");
            exit(1);
        }


    }

    pthread_join(handler_thread, NULL);

    printf("server shut down.\n");


    return 0;
}

//client code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sock_descriptor, portno, n;

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    char buffer[256];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }


    portno = atoi(argv[1]);

    sock_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock_descriptor < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: creating socket!\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    memset((char *)&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: connecting server!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));



    while((n = recv(sock_descriptor, buffer, 255, 0)) > 0)
    {
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        printf("Server:%s\n", buffer);
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("Client:");
        gets(buffer);
        send(sock_descriptor, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    }



    if (n <= 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: reading from socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Threading is so complicated.  Instead of spawning a thread to handle each request, you might get better performance and easier programming both, by using `select` or `epoll` instead.  Just a thought - I've done it the way you are doing it here, but I wouldn't again.  I'll have to look closer at your code to see if I can spot your issue.

Comment: thank you so much for your advice but unfortunately i got no knowledge about select and epoll you're talking about. i got some knowledge about pthread library (including mutexes, condition variables, threads) and some knowledge about socket api in c.

Comment: Why 'pthread_join(handler_thread, NULL);' ?

Comment: Don't use gets(). It's dangerous and deprecated.

Comment: 'send(sock_descriptor, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);' why send 256 bytes every time?

Comment: Martin i know gets is dangerous i used it for simplicity and debugging. i was thinking it to change later. i don't know what number of bytes should i allow user to send i chose it maximum 255 characters for now. i was practicing now i will change it to multi-user chat program later when i understand basics.

Comment: first get the socket io working with a single client and single server. THEN add any multithreading ... it'll make your life easier.

Comment: Martin thank you so much i realized i wrote sizeof(buffer) instead of strlen(buffer) in send(sock_descriptor, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) statement. I changed it to normal and it worked thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Join the threads right after it has been created , accept is a blocking call (I assume you have not modified the default behavior) . Threads are complex to analyze however , the call to join wont even come since blocking accept call in while loop.

```
while(1)
 {
    //do something here 
    ...
    if( pthread_create(&handler_thread, (void *)NULL, connection_handler, (void *)new_sock) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: creating thread\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_join(handler_thread, NULL); //Use it right after creating thread
}
```

Comment: Ok . Still it is complex to analyze threaded code. Start with non threaded code then move to threads

Comment: It seems kind of pointless to start up a thread to handle your connection, and then immediately join that thread before returning to the accept loop.  At that point, the thread has to be done before the next request can be made - you may as well not bother running the thread at all.  I don't see how it makes any difference.  If you opportunistically joined the thread you could accept other requests in the mean time ( a select or epoll would also allow you to handle multiple sockets from a single thread )

Comment: @DanFarrell I understand that using threads this way hasn't any significance. I was changed it to handle one client to try to solve the problem i mentioned above. I solved the problem thanks of Martin James. I will turn it to multi-user multithreaded chat application. Is'nt there a way to do that with pthread library and socket api ? Now i've created a global thread pool to assign threads to each client communicating with server. Do you have any suggestions ?